# Security warning with PHP

Tags: php

My review script is called using this type of code:

```
<?php $id="84"; include "../../reviews/main.php"; ?>
```

Each page has a different unique ID.

This is the script for this page https://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/beaches/armybeach.php

Even though the page displays secure there is one element that's not.
Check this page with https://www.whynopadlock.com and you will see:

```
Number of insecure items: 1
Insecure URL: http://www.to-hawaii.com/
Found in: https://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/beaches/armybeach.php
```

Is there a way to make this script secure so this warning is not displayed?

Comment: Firefox shows ***no*** insecure items on your page, although, the canonical like is insecure, `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/beaches/armybeach.php" />` which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I know. But you see this secure warning on https://www.whynopadlock.com

Comment: You should be using relative paths if you have any scripts pointing to `http://` that are hard coded. Plus using `//site` as references will automatically pull from `https` if any of those have them available. This could be the issue here.

Comment: I am already using relative paths and I dont have any http:// urls.

Comment: view your HTML source and find `http://` anywhere. I once had that problem. It could also be an image, who knows, css, could be anything. A db file...

Comment: HTML source revealed `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` and `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/beaches/armybeach.php" />` and `<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/TouristAttraction">` and a bunch or URL's with `http://` so that could just be a false positive (you can safely ignore those). The first two need to be taken care of.

Comment: I removed all references to http while testing and the only thing that gave an error was <?php $id="84"; include "../../reviews/main.php"; ?> that's why I was wondering if there is a "secure" way of telling this script to do that. Otherwise the page is 100% secure with the canonical tag and the other tags you mentioned.